# How to find the simple events of this problem

Tags: probability

> A hospital has 3 stations to serve patients. The physicians are assigned randomly to the stations, and hence the patients have no station preference. 3 patients arrive and their station selection is observed.

Since every patient has 3 different stations to choose from, there are $3^3 = 27$ different possible combinations. I want to define a simple event so I can more easily calculate the probabilities relating to the question, but I'm having trouble doing so.

My idea was that $\{x,y,z\}$ could denote $x$ amount of patients arriving at station 1, $y$ amount of patients at station 2 and $z$ amount of patients at station 3. So $\{2,0,1\}$ in this case means that station 2 didn't receive any patients. The problem with this is that you can't distinguish the patients in this way.

But the trouble is defining the simple event in this case. Is "a patient arrives at a station" a correct simple event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to look at 3 patient's selections separately, because these are three independent random outcomes. A correct simple event for *j*th patient (*j*=1,2,3) is {arrival at station *s*, *s*=1,2,3}. A correct simple event set for the whole setting is then Euclidean cube of individual events set. It'll be Euclidean product of *n* individual copies for the general case of *n* patients.